Performance issues with SwiftUI/SwiftData when using larger datasets
SwiftUI Using a NavigatonSplitview on the left side to list an array of objects and a detail view on the right side to modify parameters of the objects in a TextField, I have severe performance issues.
When running the code below as a SwiftUI app on MacOS, I have a very sluggish UI experience. Which are the improvements I can make to have a fluent UI?
The UI is fluent for a limited number of objects in the array persons, but for numbers such as 1000 the performance is very slow.
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    
    @Query(sort: [SortDescriptor(\Person.lastName, order: .forward)]) private var persons: [Person]
    @State private var selectedPerson: Person?
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Add Person") {
            addPerson()
        }
        
        NavigationSplitView {
            // Left Column: List of Persons
            List(persons, selection: $selectedPerson) { person in
                Text("\(person.firstName) \(person.lastName)")
                    .tag(person)
            }
            .navigationTitle("People")
        } detail: {
            // Right Column: Detail View to Edit Person
            if let selectedPerson = selectedPerson {
                DetailView(person: selectedPerson)
            } else {
                Text("Select a person")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func addPerson() {
        for _ in 0..<1000 {
            let tempPerson = (Person(firstName: randomString(length: 10), lastName: randomString(length: 10)))
            modelContext.insert(tempPerson)
            
        }
        try! modelContext.save()
    }
    
    func randomString(length: Int) -> String {
        let characters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
        return String((0..<length).compactMap { _ in characters.randomElement() })
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @Bindable var person: Person
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            TextField("First Name", text: $person.firstName)
            TextField("Last Name", text: $person.lastName)
        }
        .padding()
        .navigationTitle("Edit Person")
    }
}

@Model
class Person {
    
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    
    init(firstName: String, lastName: String) {
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
    }
}

Thanks in advance for any help.

Could not replicate your problem. Using your code as is, on macOS 15.3 using Xcode 16.2,
the UI response is very good, very fast. Just tried with 10000, and still very good.

Could you add Text("count: \(persons.count)") before the Button.
To see the number of persons you really have in SwiftData.

Thank you for checking this out!
Indeed for 1000 persons it was fluent (in fact there where indeed more added then I thought), but starting from 10.000 the problem is visible.
I have made a screencast (https://youtu.be/Zx3BPAXXwLo) with 100.000 entries. When I select a person it takes some time, and when typing a value in the TextFields, there is a significant delay.
I have macOSX 15.2 and Xcode 16.2. My machine is a MacBook Air M3 16GB. Do you see something different?

with 100.000 entries the response is very slow and typing into the TextFields is very very slow. SwiftUI List and other views are not meant to have so many entries for a user to scroll through. You should restrict (eg filter) the entries to a manageble number. It is not acceptable UX for a user to scroll through 100.000 entries.

I know this is hypothetical but in my real app I have such a behavior with much less rows, but where the "persons" contain much more then 2 strings. It would seem more logical that the entire list is not refreshed when changing (in this example) only firstName or lastName, but only the object where changes are made to.

There are some ways to handle queries with large result sets, first of all if you are only supporting macOS 15 or higher you can add an index on the field you are sorting on to your model
@Model
class Person {
    #Index<Person>([\.lastName]) 
    //...
}

Then we have another problem and that is that the macro @Query gets triggered every time your view changes so when typing in a TextField the macro is executed basically for each key stroke.
One way around this is to not use the @Query macro and instead manually trigger the fetch. Below is a simplified example where .task(id:) is used to execute the fetch
struct ContentView: View {
    //...
    @State private var persons: [Person] = []
    @State private var triggerFetch: Date = .now

    var body: some View {
        //...
        NavigationSplitView {
            //...
        } detail: {
            if let selectedPerson = selectedPerson {
                DetailView(person: selectedPerson, trigger: $triggerFetch)
            } else //...
        }
         .task(id: triggerFetch) {
            persons = fetchData()
        }
    }

    func fetchData() -> [Person] {
        let fetchDescriptor = FetchDescriptor(sortBy: [SortDescriptor(\Person.lastName, order: .forward)])
        
        return (try? modelContext.fetch(fetchDescriptor)) ?? []
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @Bindable var person: Person
    @Binding var trigger: Date
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            TextField("First Name", text: $person.firstName)
            TextField("Last Name", text: $person.lastName)
        }
        .onSubmit {
            trigger = .now
        }
        .padding()
        .navigationTitle("Edit Person")
    }
}

If you still want to use the @Query macro an option is to not edit an object in the persons array directly but instead use a sheet or like in the example below make the DetailView handle the editing in a more isolated way.
struct DetailView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    
    let id: Person.ID?
    @State var firstName = ""
    @State var lastName = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            TextField("First Name", text: $firstName)
            TextField("Last Name", text: $lastName)
            
            Divider()
            
            Button("Save", systemImage: "square.and.arrow.down") {
                guard let id, let person = modelContext.model(for: id) as? Person else {
                    dismiss()
                    return
                }
                
                person.firstName = firstName
                person.lastName = lastName
                
                try? modelContext.save()
                dismiss()
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .navigationTitle("Edit Person")
        .onAppear {
            guard let id, let person = modelContext.model(for: id) as? Person else {
                dismiss()
                return
            }
            
            firstName = person.firstName
            lastName = person.lastName
        }
    }
}

The call to the view is then changed to
DetailView(id: selectedPerson.id)

The code above is just a quick example on how to make the editing isolated from the list and the @Query to avoid unnecessary updates, the example code itself can surely be improved in many ways.
